# Implement objective-c UITableViewDelegate and Datasource in seperate class error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to objective c. I am trying to implement a custom UITableViewDataSource and delegate.

I created an NSObject subclass and added the following code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface TableViewDataSourceDelegate : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

I get this error.

```
Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIViewController', superclass of 'TableViewDataSourceDelegate'
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Can you show more code? Where are you using TableViewDataSourceDelegate?

Comment: The code above is from the header file of the subclass NSObject i created. There is no other code. Inside the .m file is just this "implementation TableViewDataSourceDelegate end". I want to use inside the main view controller where i have an uitableview. I want the delegate methods and the datasource on a seperate class.

Comment: I think you may need to define the minimum required interface methods definition for uitableview datasource and delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

`UI*` classes are part of `UIKit`. Not `Foundation`. You can just import `UIKit` and remove the `Foundation`, because the former depends on latter and imports it automatically.